# Arcgis, Convert analyse result in numeric value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python

I have a problem that seems really simple but blocking me... in Arcgis i have script python where i want to extract the resolution of a raster and use this result like numeric value for use in a mathematical function.

But when i try to use it, here i have my problem because it is not a numeric value. So i want to convert the result of my request (Get raster Properties) in numeric value. Some body have a solution?

> > > a = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(r"Topographie\Raster d'élévation \Lidar\Elevation LastReturns.tif","CELLSIZEX")
> > >       Result: Cellsize in x direction = 1.000000
> > >
> > > type(a)
> > >       Result: class 'arcpy.arcobjects.arcobjects.Result'

```
and if i try :
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the Esri help file at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000m7000000 which says:

> The Python result of this tool returns a geoprocessing Result object. In order to obtain the string value, use the Result object's getOutput method.

So try using getOutput on your variable *a* as in the example on that page:

```
import arcpy
#Get the geoprocessing result object
elevSTDResult = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management("c:/data/elevation", "STD")
#Get the elevation standard deviation value from geoprocessing result object
elevSTD = elevSTDResult.getOutput(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just call the result by index:

```
import arcpy
#Get the geoprocessing result object
elevSTDResult = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management("c:/data/elevation", "STD")
#Get the elevation standard deviation value from geoprocessing result object
elevSTD = elevSTDResult[0]
```